# How (Where) to save data (like: comments, caption) when creating an iOS App with Swift using Amazon (AWS) Mobile Hub?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to build an iOS App ( just like Instagram, Twitter, Facebook, etc) with Swift using Amazon Mobile Hub.

Now I have some trouble on where (how) to save data (like: comments, caption), AWS DynamoDB?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options when storing data in the cloud with AWS Mobile Hub. Amazon DynamoDB is definitely a popular way to go for mobile apps, since you can have the app talk directly to the highly scalable NoSQL database service without a middle software layer. In order to set that up, use the NoSQL database feature in Mobile Hub's console. Hub will help construct the schema and authorization policies, so that you can use Amazon DynamoDB directly from the app.

Other options for persisting data include Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service), Amazon ElastiCache, and Amazon Aurora (MySQL compliant database) in RDS (Remote Database Service), however, with Aurora you would likely want to put a serverless API in front of it, since you would not want mobile app-scale connection volume going directly to the database server, and you need to control your access policy.

If you're in a city with an AWS Loft, you can always stop by to get help on these sorts of things.
https://aws.amazon.com/start-ups/loft/

AWS also has online training materials that may help you.
https://aws.amazon.com/training/